# Enable stereoscopic 3D

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

When I play Pokémon Y, I've noticed that the game disables stereoscopic 3D when not in combat; i.e. the green 3D LED is off and moving the 3D slider doesn't do anything.

Looking at the settings, I can see options to set the text speed (slow, normal, fast), but I can't find anything related to stereoscopy. Is it possible to enable the feature outside of combat, and how?

Comment: You're...playing Pokemon Y already?  Where'd you get it?

Comment: it was released earlier than intended in some regions like Italy and Canada IIRC

Comment: @fbueckert I preordered it and received my copy yesterday. When playing, I saw quite a number of people playing it already over the P.S.S. so I thought it was already released. Guess I was wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, October 12th is the official release date.  Score for you, I guess.

Comment: @fbueckert So, should I delete the question and undelete it in 3 days?

Comment: Nah; you're playing it with a legit copy.  You just got lucky with somebody breaking street date.

Comment: But you have earned the undying envy of the community. (For three days, anyways.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3D effects are not enabled 100% of the time in this game - in fact you'll rarely see them outside of battle.  This is apparently a deliberate design choice on the part of the developers (presumably not to wear out the gimmick).

Comment: Source: I've seen this mentioned in multiple professional reviews of the game.

Comment: Yea. The 3D LED is actually the exact indicator you would need. It is only turned on for games and applications that support 3D.

Comment: I've noticed it being disabled during horde battles (1 vs 5) as well as enabled when in caves. I think it's to keep a playable framerate.

Comment: That would be reasonable as well, yeah.